# Call function inside of another function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Using the factory pattern, i wrote snippets of code that use firebase cloud functions :

```
//Notice that when instantiated it does calculations and returns a value
function sumAndMultiply(int number) {
    function sum(i) {
        return i + 1;
    }
    function multiply(i) {
        return i * 3;
    }

    const x = sum(number);
    const y = multiply(x);
    return y;
}
```

everting working fine, but, what i can make if i need to unit test `multiply()` or `sum()` function?

```
describe('Unit testing', () => {

    it('test sum function', () => {

        //How i can call sum function without call sumAndMultiply?
        let result = sum(3);
        expect(result == 4);
    });

    it('test multiply function', () => {

        //How i can call multiply function without call sumAndMultiply?
        let result = multiply(3);
        expect(result == 9);
    });
});
```

As I'm talking about unit testing, one idea is to avoid editing the code used for production, but changes that make the code more readable or better are accepted

Comment: the code posted is not JavaScript

Comment: Sorry, i aciddently typed the variables, fixed....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that your code is tightly coupled with the implementation of sum and multiply functions. This makes testing way harder, and testing the units of sum and multiply would take a lot of effort.

One way of solving this code smell is to use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This way, you would provide both the `sum` and `multiply` functions, but the interface of `sumAndMultiply`functions would need to change. This way, your code would become:

```js
//Notice that when instantiated it does calculations and returns a value
function sumAndMultiply(number, sum, multiply) {
    const x = sum(number);
    const y = multiply(x);
    return y;
}

function sum(i) {
  return i + 1;
}

function multiply(i) {
  return i * 3;
}
```

That way, you INJECT these functions. Good thing is that now we can unit test both our sum and multiply functions as you've sugested. Even better, we can now mock our `sum` and `multiply` functions on `sumAndMultiply`.